# SqlException unhandled on C# when trying to call a certain column on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlexception

I have this code on C#

[image]

and I got NoIDStaffC from

```
NoIDStaffC = dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Every time I try to run it, it keep telling me that `SqlException` was unhandled.

And this is my table in SQL Server :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because `A002` isn't quoted in the query - so it's being treated as a column name instead of text to compare with.

You can either add single quotes around it in your built string or [parameterize your query](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) (preferred) to fix the problem.

Comment: where should I put the single quotes?

Comment: "SELECT NamaStaff FROM MsStaff WHERE NoIDStaff = '" + NoIDStaffC + "'"

Comment: Please - **always** use **parametrized queries** and **do not** just concatenate together your SQL commands with single quotes and stuff!

Comment: Strongly agree with @marc_s, building queries via string concatenation is not good at all

Comment: @marc_s I'm really new at this. How to use parametrized queries?

Comment: @AdyanaPermatasari there's a link to a tutorial on how to do it in my answer

Comment: @mlorbetske oh yeah I just saw that. Thanks for all your help. mlorbetske, marc_s I'll study the parametrized queries.